# Exercise 10, Section 6.3 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, minimal-polynomials

> Let $V$ be the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices over the field $F$. Let $A$ be a fixed $n\times n$ matrix. Let $T$ be the linear operator on $V$ defined by $T(B)=AB$. Show that the minimal polynomial for $T$ is the minimal polynomial for $A$.

**My attempt:** Let $E=\{E_{pq}|\ p,q\in J_n\}$ is basis of $V$. Then $P=[T]_E=\begin{bmatrix} A& & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & A\\ \end{bmatrix}$. It’s easy to check $P^k= \begin{bmatrix} A^k& & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & A^k\\ \end{bmatrix}$. Let $f\in F[x]$. Then $f =\sum_{i=0}^nc_i\cdot x^i$. So $$f(P)=\sum_{i=0}^n c_i\cdot P^i= \sum_{i=0}^n c_i\cdot \begin{bmatrix} A^i& & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & A^i\\ \end{bmatrix}=  \begin{bmatrix} f(A)& & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & f(A)\\ \end{bmatrix}.$$ Thus $f(P)=0$$\iff$$f(A)=0$. Let $m_T$ and $m_A$ be minimal polynomial of $T$ and $A$, respectively. Since $m_T(P)=0$ and $m_A(A)=0$, we have $m_T(A)=0$ and $m_A(P)=0$. So $m_A|m_T$ and $m_T|m_A$. Since $m_T$ and $m_A$ are monic, we have $m_T=m_A$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: Above solution is inspired by [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4620454/861687) of lemma 1 section 6.4 by Hoffman and Kunze.

Comment: Alternatively note once you've shown that the set of annihilating polynomials for $T$ equals that for $A$, then clearly the monic polynomial of least degree in that set is the minimal polynomial for both $T$ and $A$.

Comment: @blargoner yeah. That’s a nice (slight) variation to show $m_T=m_A$, i.e. if set of annihilating polynomials for $T$ equals that for $A$, then $m_T=m_A$ follows by uniqueness of monic generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.

As an alternative approach, there is no actual need to compute the matrix $[T]_E$. Instead, simply note that we have $f(T)(B) = f(A)B$ for $f \in F[x]$. From there, it is just as easy to argue that $m_A(T) = 0$ and $m_T(A) = 0$.