# Exercise 13, Section 6.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

> Let $V$ be the space of $n\times n$ matrices over $F$. Let $A$ be a fixed $n \times n$ matrix over $F$. Let $T$ and $U$ be the linear operators on V defined by $T(B)=AB$ and $U(B)=AB-BA$.
>
> (a) True or false? If $A$ is diagonalizable (over $F$), then $T$ is diagonalizable.
>
> (b) True or false? If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $U$ is diagonalizable.

**My attempt:** (a) Suppose $A$ is diagonalizable. By theorem 6 section 6.4, $A$ is diagonalizable$\iff$$m_A=(x-c_1)\cdots (x-c_k)$, where $c_i\in F$ and $c_i\neq c_j$, if $i\neq j$. By [exercise 10 section 6.3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4622220/861687), $m_A=m_T$. By theorem 6 section 6.4, $T$ is diagonalizable.

(b) Suppose $A$ is diagonalizable. Let $R:V\to V$ such that $R(B)=BA$. Then $U=T-R$. By (a), $T$ and $R$ are diagonalizable. **How to show $T-R$ is diagonalizable?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $TR=RT$, as for any matrix $B$, $$TR(B)=T(BA)=ABA=R(AB)=RT(B).$$

Therefore, $T,R$ can be made diagonal simultaneously in a basis, which means $T-R$ is diagonal in that basis.

Comment: I think, result “$T$, $R$ can be made diagonal simultaneously in a basis” is in next section (simultaneously triangulation and diagonalization) of book.

Comment: Can we prove this result without much headache?

Answer (score 2):

As a hint towards an alternate, more constructive solution, I'll point out the following: if $v\in F^n$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $w\in F^n$ is an eigenvector of $A^T$, then the matrix $vw^T\in V$ is an eigenvector of both $T$ and $U$. I'll leave it as an exercise to show that matrices of that form in fact span all of $V$.